# Convert a Json String to Struct in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a string filed with following data :

[{"S": "Value1"},{"S": "Value2"}]

I am trying to use from_json

```
Select from_json('[{"S": "Value1"},{"S": "Value2"}]','ARRAY<STRUCT<S:STRING>>') as column_name
```

but I keep getting an error related to syntax.

Final goal is to have an array field with below schema :

```
 |-- column_name: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- S: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

`from_json` only accepts a `Column` as first parameter, you can not pass a `String`, meaning that if you have this:

```
+---------------------------------+
|features                         |
+---------------------------------+
|[{"S": "Value1"},{"S": "Value2"}]|
+---------------------------------+
```

You can use this expression: `expr("from_json(features, 'array<struct<S:string>>')")` to get this:

```
+--------------------+
|features            |
+--------------------+
|[{Value1}, {Value2}]|
+--------------------+
```

Good luck!